# mfc copy certain sections of a CString

Tags: c++, mfc, stl, cstring

Let's say I have a CString variable carrying the string "Bob Evans". I want to copy from position 4 until the end of the original CString to a new CString, but I am having trouble finding semantics examples for this:

```
CString original("Bob Evans");
// Below is what I'm trying to do
// CString newStr = original.copy(4, original.GetLength());
```

I have also thought about copying the variable **original** to a STL C++ string, but achieving this isn't all that easy either in terms of the conversion. What would be your advice regarding this? I could make the string to be stored in a STL string to begin with, but this would be one of the last resort as I didn't want to restructure a lot of code just to store the data in STL string instead of CString. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
newStr = original.Mid(4);
```

Comment: Thanks. The Mid function works very well for me. Quite awkward to me why Microsoft names this function Mid() though.

Comment: They have .Left, .Mid and .Right - makes sense once you start using them.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't all that hard to turn a `CString` into a standard string; the only glitch is that you're probably using Unicode if you take the default settings for your MFC program. That means you'll want to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

I haven't tested this, but I think the default conversions will let this 'just work'. Otherwise cast the CString to LPCTSTR.

```
std::wstring copyOfOriginal(original);
```