# How to copy part of CString to a new one?

Tags: c++, mfc

I got a `CString str`

I want to copy `str[3]~ str[5]` to a brand new one.
I tried C++ char* 's method, not compatible.

So what is the right way do this in VC++

Thank you,

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014550/mfc-copy-certain-sections-of-a-cstring) might help you ...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the the [MID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300543%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function?

str.Mid( 3, 3 ) should give you the substring you are looking for.

Updated reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c90k3d(v=vs.80).aspx